# How to extract the first 2 CHARACTERS from a string in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, utf-8, substring, string-length

Using left() or substring() I can get the first 2 bytes, which is NOT equal to the first 2 characters.

Using PhpMyadmin, this is what I see when I browse the string value in the table:
%D8%A3%D8%B9%D8%B7%D9%8A.
This is equivalent to the Arabic word التقنيات

This is the output of SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%';

```
character_set_client utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database utf8
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8
character_set_server utf8
character_set_system utf8
character_sets_dir /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

I am using collation: utf8_general_ci for the table and the column.

Comment: From the manual: "*Returns the leftmost len characters ... This function is **multi-byte safe***".

Comment: I am using this substring function as follows: select substring(substring_index(url,'/',-1),1,200)
from sc_services, but the value returned is obviously wrong, because the resulting string ends with %D, while it should end with something ilke %D1 or %D2. There must be 2 char after the percetage sign.

Comment: If you have in your database what you're showing here as an example, You're not using utf8 correctly, Looks like you're storing CP-1256 in a utf8 table, if you were storing the data correctly, You'd be getting readable output & I guess sub-string would have worked for you just fine.

Comment: try using convert or cast functions in mysql before applying your substring & see if that would help.

Comment: Hmm .. I am getting the data from a PostgreSQL database. I automatically generated the insert statement using PGAdminIII (IDE for PostgreSQL development) and used them against MySQL (No change in syntax is needed)

Comment: I tried cast and convert, but they did not help.

Comment: Moreover, using length and char_length on the string, return the same result. I thought it would be different.

Answer (score 0):

"%D8%A3%D8%B9%D8%B7%D9%8A" is URL-encoded data. You should store text as text, without any additional encodings, so that can be processed by the database. That is, when you look at the data in your tables in phpMyAdmin you should see أعطي instead of %D8%A3%D8%B9%D8%B7%D9%8A.

There is no built-in function for decoding data in this format in MySQL. You can [define a stored function](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/urlencodeurldecode-mysql) to do the decoding, or use a function defined in the programming language you use in your client software, such as `urldecode` in PHP or the `URLDecoder` class in Java.